# Partly sharing detail records of a master-detail relationship

Tags: security, sharing, apex-managed-sharing, sharing-rule, apex-sharing

In our data model, we have several objects that are details of account (master-detail) relationship. I want a profile to have access to the records of Object A and B if they are the owner of the master account but only see the records of Object A but not B, if they are not the owner of the master account. There is only one master account that the profile will not have access to so doing it manually may be an option.

I was hoping to do this with sharing rules but noticed detail objects don't have a sharing rule.

Comment: In second case when should see records of Object A - should the user also see master Account records? I.e. there's Account1 where Owner is User1 and detail records ObjectA1 and ObjectB1. User2, as you described should see ObjectA1 but not ObjectB1. Should he see Account1?

Comment: Ideally not but it should be fine if there is no way

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 `Master-Detail` Options available:

> Select the minimum access level required on the Master record to
>   create, edit, or delete related Detail records:
>
> - **Read Only**: Allows users with at least Read access to the Master    record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.
> - **Read/Write**: Allows users with at least Read/Write access to the Master record to    create, edit, or delete related Detail records.

More likely you'd have to use `Lookup Relationship`